# Why should I click double on an 'a href' attribute to reload the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, href

I have such a problem:

When I click on the element the url changes but PHP code doesn't run, but when I click it again or just push 'Enter' in the url, or push F5 the page reloads and PHP code runs

```
        <a href="?action=out" title="Forget me!">
            <img src="images/icons/exit.png" id="exit" class="ava">
        </a>
```

Here was my html code.
Here is PHP one:

```
        if($_GET['action']=='out')
           {
               //do smth. here
            }
```

What is the problem, I just can't get it..

maybe I just have to use JS (location.reload() and so on), but I think that it will be not a good descision...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There isn't really enough information to answer this for you.  You probably have something in your code that is changing data and querying for something before that change occurs.  Post a code snippet that fully reproduces the problem.  Also, do some basic debugging on your end to figure out where your script is failing.

Comment: Did you try more than one browser? When you said the URL changes, does any part of the new page load?

Comment: @TecBrat Yes I did, this problem is in the code...(

Comment: The first thing I'd do then is var_dump $_GET and see what happens.

Comment: @TecBrat this shows me my "action" right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe your href is wrong you have information in the href but no page assigned, if you are sourcing your own page try

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=out'; ?>" title="Forget Me!">
```

Comment: That will work the same as just `<a href="?action=out">..</a>`.

Comment: @putvande so what can I do?)